# Placing a border under both image and text in HTML , but border was under text when image is too big

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to place a border after the div tag , but the line showed around the text , not after below the image on left , how can i fix it ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> This is an demo </title>
        <style>
            .left { float: left; }
            .content {
                clear: both;
                border-color: #666666;
                border-bottom: 3px solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <img class="left" src="61add42atw1dnf1k4h4qzj.jpg" />
            <p> This is a not so long paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

How can i place the border a little lower ?

Thanks !

Comment: @Helen  it's a minimal case , only the part dwelling in <head>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .content div, replace the clear:both with overflow:hidden

```
.content {
                overflow: hidden;
                border-color: #666666;
                border-bottom: 3px solid;
            }
```

Comment: [This is the reason why it works](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). I personally don't think it's worth relying on a side-effect of the `overflow` property, sometimes as requiring coupling with other properties, to achieve simple clearing, just to avoid adding an extra element, but the authors of the article sure seems to...

Answer (score 2):

You need to `clear` the current `float`:

Either:

```
<br clear="left" />  <!-- or "right" or "all" -->
```

Or:

```
<div style="clear: left;"></div> <!-- or "right" or "both" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left;` for all:

- Image has already left class
- Div .content should have same i.e; wrapper div
- paragraph inside content

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve here but if you would like to have a div with an `img` and `p` below each other then you could just get rid of `class="left"` in the `img` and apply `float: left` to the `content` class.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> This is an demo </title>
        <style>
            .left { float: left; }
            .content {
                float: left; /* can get rid of this if you want your div to have the page witdh */
                border-color: #666666;
                border-bottom: 3px solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="image.jpg" />
            <p> This is a not so long paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```